# How do I get the screen point of an object in 3D space in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to match the end of a line drawn with the line renderer to a point in space that is only a few units from the camera and is over an object that could be very far from the camera or very close. When I use WorldToScreenPoint I get results that are incomprehensible to me. Setting position 0 is where I get the incomprehensible results. The code is a component of the object I am trying to get the screen position of. Any help is appreciated.

```
foreach (int i in identifiers)
{
    GameObject lineHolder = new GameObject();
    lineHolder.transform.position = transform.position;
    lineHolder.transform.parent = transform;
    LineRenderer line = lineHolder.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
    lineHolders.Add(lineHolder);
    line.positionCount = 2;
    line.SetPosition(0, Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, master.screenPoint.z)));
    line.widthMultiplier = .1f;
    line.SetPosition(1, master.controlPanel.controlElements[i].position);
}
```

This is how I get the "screenPoint" in the "master" code I am referring to:

```
screenPoint = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(controlPanel.transform.position);
```

The "controlPanel" object is 5 units from the camera. I am trying to keep the lines from being drawn under objects in the control panel, which are just objects and are not part of a canvas, but stay at 5 units from the camera.

I converted from a screen point to a world point. Here is the corrected code that works:

```
foreach (int i in identifiers)
                    {
                        GameObject lineHolder = new GameObject();
                        lineHolder.transform.position = transform.position;
                        lineHolder.transform.parent = transform;
                        LineRenderer line = lineHolder.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
                        lineHolders.Add(lineHolder);
                        line.positionCount = 2;
                        Vector3 screenPoint = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
                        line.SetPosition(0, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(screenPoint.x, screenPoint.y, master.controlPanel.transform.localPosition.z)));
                        line.widthMultiplier = .1f;
                        line.SetPosition(1, master.controlPanel.controlElements[i].position);
```

Comment: LineRenderer.SetPosition needs a world position, but you assign a screen point to it, that's wrong.

Comment: Thank you shingo. I converted from a screen point to a world point and it worked.